# incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int. What do I do?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I am mainly confused on how the int[] and int work, what they are, and how to make them compatible. Would anyone be willing to help?
public class MultiplyMe
{

```
/**
* Swag
*/
public static int c=2;
public static int d=3;
public static void main (String[] args)
{
c = doubleAndTripleMe(c,d); //Error
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
}
static int[] doubleAndTripleMe(int f, int g)
{
int[] ans = new int[2];
ans[c] = f*2;

ans[d] = g*3;
return ans;
}
}
```

Comment: this is java, not javascript.

Comment: If you don't understand what `int` and `int[]` mean, then Stack Overflow is not the right place to get help. You need to follow a tutorial from the beginning. This is not a tutorial website.

Answer (score 2):

**int** is a datatype for numbers, like: *1, 2 and 10*

**int[]** is a datatype for an array of ints, *like [1, 2, 3]*

You will have to change your variable *c* to the same datatype as the one you return in your function.

Answer (score 2):

Variables declared as "int[]" are a list of integers.  Variables declared simply as "int" are a single integer.

Therefore, as they are different object "types" (one is a list, that happens to be able to contain integers - the other is just a single integer value), then you cannot directly assign one to the other.

In terms of your specific script example, where you are doing

```
c = doubleAndTripleMe(c,d);
```

instead the "c" at the beginning of this line needs to be replaced with a variable that's been declared as int[] (since that's the type of object that the doubleAndTripleMe() method is returning)

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?
int is an integer, a number
int[] is a table of integers
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arrays.asp

Comment: What's `JTable` got to do with the OP question?

Comment: sorry, fixed link